# An opensource equivalent to Photoshop that has Lasso and Warp tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photo-editing, open-source

Using Photoshop, I can edit the image by using the lasso tool and warp tool, but Photoshop is not open source, I need an open source software to edit the image by using the same tools.

I tried GIMP but there is no warp tool in that. Can you please suggest some open source software with lasso and warp tool?

Comment: I don't have GIMP on the machine I'm currently on, but it does appear there is a warp tool: http://fineartamerica.com/blogs/how-to-find-the-gimp-warp-tool.html

Comment: Its hidden in menu *"Filers - Distorts - IWarp..."* for  freestyle warping (but it lacks presicion). The cage tool transform tool (see [answer below](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/22088)) is quite good as well.

Comment: I think your edit would be better as a different question now because the edit doesnt match the title.  May I suggest you make a new question in regards to the warp tool?

Comment: Hi, good question, sorry that I can't help. But, could you mean "wand tool" instead of "warp tool" ?

Answer (score 5):

If you do a Google search for `Lasso Tool in Gimp` you will receive a few links and the first link in the search is from GIMP's [documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-free-select.html) that shows the `Free Selection Tool`

[image]

Per an insert from Gimp

> The Free Selection tool, or Lasso, lets you create a selection by
>   drawing it free-hand with the pointer, while holding down the left
>   mouse button (or, for a stylus, pressing it against the tablet). When
>   you release the mouse button, the selection is closed by connecting
>   the current pointer location to the start location with a straight
>   line. You can go outside the edge of the image display and come back
>   in if you want to. The Lasso is often a good tool to use for “roughing
>   in” a selection; it is not so good for precise definition. Experienced
>   users find that it is often convenient to begin with the lasso tool,
>   but then switch to QuickMask mode for detail work.

---

If I search for `warp tool in Gimp` it provides a link to GIMP's [documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tools-transform.html) on the `Transform Tools`

[image]

An insert per Gimp

> Inside the Transformation tool dialog, you will find eight tools to
>   modify the presentation of the image or the presentation of an element
>   of the image, selection, layer or path. Each transform tool has an
>   Option dialog and an Information dialog to set parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have editted my question, Please have a look. I can warp but there is no preview option in Gimp. I have explained it in detail, in my updated section. Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to desktop apps there are online photo editing tools as well. One is Pixlr: http://pixlr.com/ and has a free, no-account-needed editor that you can test out its functionality with.

I'm not sure of its (or it's other versions') complete feature set -- but I do see on the Pixlr Editor version that you can test for free: lasso as well as pinch and bloat tools that may or may not warp/distort similar to what you need.

I don't know how their pricing is set up - if at all. I was able to test the online Pixlr Editor and save an image to my desktop without creating an account.

Answer (score 0):

old answer, but found the solution on https://www.freephototool.com
there is wrap and Polygon Selection tools.